# Wheres my saved profile in Dirt 3?

Tags: games-for-windows-live, dirt-3

I have an online "Games for Windows" account and use it when playing Dirt 3. Recently, when I signed in in the game it welcomed me as if it was the the first time starting the game.

Where did my saved profile go?

Comment: [This forum post](http://forums.xbox.com/gfw/technical_support/f/253/t/8132.aspx) appears to detail a series of problems and potential fixes for GfWL not saving your DiRT3 game. The save games should be located in C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XLive\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I had a new *Documents* folder since I reinstalled Windows. Thankfully I backed up the old one. 
The profile data is located at: **C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\My Games\DiRT3\savegame**

I thought that the profile data was saved in the cloud with a online account. To bad that isn't the case.